# Remove Duplicate Entries - Excel Data Table

Tags: excel, duplicates

1- The file contains call records against "Account" numbers.
2- The "Account" records are supposed to be unique without duplication.
3- "Call Remarks" are updated against each "Account" number whenever a new call is made against a particular "Account" number.
4- "Calling date" can be either **empty** or have the latest calling date.
5- One of the data entry operators made a mistake by copying the entire record with updated remarks directly into the master sheet rather than just updating the "Call remarks".
6- This has caused duplication of records.

[Sample Duplicate Record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbZlv.png)

**SOLUTION REQUIRED:**

If any "Account" has **duplicate** entry then only the entry with **latest** "Calling date" should be kept while deleting all other duplicate entries.

The table name is **dt**. I was able to find which records have duplicate entries by making a "Duplicate check" column and writing below expression:

=COUNTIF(dt[Account],[@Account])

This helped in knowing which Accounts have multiple entries. What I am unable to think of is how to remove duplicate entries without manually checking the criteria mentioned. This is a sample from the actual file. The complete data consists of more than 100,000 records so manually deleting duplicate entries is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 Create a new sheet with a copy of all your duplicated data

2 Use the "remove duplicates" function to remove lines based on "Account": don't worry about which lines to remove: the data you want will come back in next steps

3 Sort your original spreadsheet so that the line you want for each account is at the top. Sort by "Account" then by "Date" reversed so most recent date for each account is at the top

4 Then go back to your duplicate (which now has unique rows) and use vlookup to return the Call Remark and Call Date from the original: it will return the first row it finds